# Excel: Sumif Multiple Columns based on the same Criteria

Tags: excel-formula, sumifs

So I am trying to create a spreadsheet at allows a character in game to total the party inventory.

I am trying to sumif multiple columns based on the same criteria.

So say I am trying to sum all the rope they have.

In column A is the Item descriptions
In columns B-E are the different totals for each party member (one column per person)

Each party member has 50 rope, so I am expecting 200 rope.
I have used this formula:

=SUMIF(A:A,"Rope: Hemp",B:E) and it is only returning 50 as a value, If I utilise cell values (A1:A100 etc.) it returns a value of Zero.

I have been told that Sum Product could works so I also tried that:

=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A100="Rope: Hemp")*(B3:E100)) and I still get the incorrect result.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here are some photos. 
[Here is my Raw Data. As you can see I have the inventory and tallies, when you look at rope it says 150, and this was calcualted by summing the B to E cells, however as the list is going to move and grow I thought SUMIF would be better.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGyZz.png)

As stated above, I have used a SUMIF making the range Columns B through E, and it only returns a value of 50 (I'm assuming Column B)

Comment: Without example data, I only have two suggestions: 1) have you tried SUMIFS(), 2) your sumproduct needs two arrays, perhaps replace the "*" with "," and I am not sure if the criteria will function as you expect on column A. It will be easier for anyone to help with an example.

Comment: Hey @SolarMike, thank you for getting back to me I did try and add multiple images however due to repuation I am limited to 2 Links.
So I have added a photograph of my raw data.

So I tried SUMIFS with the following formula: =SUMIFS(B:E,A:A,"Rope: Hemp")
It returned and #N/A error. I think because I am trying to sum multiple columns with the same Criteria.
I also utilised the SUMPRODUCT formula as utilised above with an '*' and an ',' Which returned an #N/A and #VALUE.

I don't see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so came up with this:
    =SUMIF(A3:A40,"="&J17&"*",B3:B40)+SUMIF(A3:A40,"="&J17&"*",C3:C40)+SUMIF(A3:A40,"="&J17&"*",D3:D40)+SUMIF(A3:A40,"="&J17&"*",E3:E40)

Which works, but I can only assume that sumif only work with ONE target range... And I tried curly brackets as well...

So, I did also use cell J17 for the object you are looking for, so you can drag it down, the "*" will find all occurences of "Rope: Hemp", or "Rope: Nylon" etc. I get a total of 150 as there are only 3 characters with rope...

Hope it helps. Someone else may have a better / neater suggestion!

I just tested it by entering Rope, rapier and rations into J17 and got the results I expect.
Image of spreadsheet:
[image: based on your layout]

Comment: Hey Mike, I used your exact formula (Copy and Pasted into the Cell), and I get a blank cell. No value. Which suggests I am getting a 0 result Note I tried entering it into multiple cells but still no avail, even copied the raw data into another sheet and still returns a 0 value, I am running excel 2016

Comment: I believe I was mssing the Asterisks, let me try with them.

Edit: Still getting a zero value.....